# clustering using two or more lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to cluster words or sentences depending on if they get matched by an entry in another list.

Like so:

```
searchterms = ["windows pc", "linux laptop", "some gibberish"]
osCluster = ["windows", "linux"]
```

What I now want to do is go trough the searchterms and classify them using the osCluster list. In the end I want to have a csv like format like this:

- windows pc, windows
- linux laptop, linux
- some gibberish, N/A

for now I have something like this:

```
for searchterm in searchterms:
for os in osCluster:
    if os in searchterm:
        print searchterm, os
```

which results in:

```
windows pc windows
linux laptop linux
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

However, I would like to tag the "some gibberish" as "N/A". If I just add:

```
else:
        print searchterm
```

this will results in:

```
windows windows
windows
linux
linux linux
gibberish
gibberish
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

I understand that this is what I have written the programm to do. But I think it is the wrong way of thinking. It would be much appreaciated if you can point me in the right direction with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close.  Here are some fix-ups:

```
>>> searchterms = ["windows pc", "linux laptop", "some gibberish"]
>>> osCluster = ["windows", "linux"]

>>> for term in searchterms:
        found_cluster = 'N/A'
        for cluster in osCluster:
            if cluster in term:
                found_cluster = cluster
                break
        print('%-15s | %s' % (term, found_cluster))


windows pc      | windows
linux laptop    | linux
some gibberish  | N/A
```

Comment: @eLudium Updated to have just a single occurrence of the search term.

Comment: Thanks for help. What do I have to do if I want to add another cluster, or two, three more. Should I make some kind of csv, so I only read the first column (searchterm) and then start adding columns as clusters? So that in the end it be like: I really like windows pc (searchterm), windows(os), like(verb), ...(more clusters).